# Manipulate webpage and have it send back results using ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

so here it is:

I use ruby to get user input, the easy way..say I request 2 inputs:

```
input1 = gets.chomp

input2 = gets.chomp
```

Now I would like to send this information to say, a search engine that takes these two options separately and does the search. How can I do this? What API/Gems will be helpful for me in this case?

I know that i can take these 2 inputs and insert them into the url but its not that simple because according to the inputs the url structure is not constant..(I wouldn't want to use this way though..)
Its been a long time since I lat programmed in ruby, I know how to access webpages and things like that, but I want to manipulate and receive back. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about some front-end of a site without any API access or sophisticated JS logic, you could simply use [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) gem which allows you to do something like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page  = agent.get('http://google.com/')

form = page.forms.first
form['field_name_1'] = input1
form['field_name_2'] = input2

page = agent.submit(form, form.buttons.first)
puts page
```

→ Check out the [official documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/) for [more](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html) [examples](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html)

If you are going to use third party REST API you should better try something like [faraday](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/faraday) or other [popular gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) (depending on your taste and particular task).

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

From what I understand, you want to encode your two inputs in a URL, send them to an API and receive the results back.

You can use the [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) library from the Ruby stdlib. Here's the example with dynamic parameters from the docs:

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
params = { :limit => 10, :page => 3 }
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

Or you can use some gems to wrap it up for you. [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) seems quite popular. You can do it as simple as

```
HTTParty.get('http://foo.com/resource.json', query: {limit: 10})
```